# TCL assign variable from a command

Tags: tcl, expect

In TCL/Expect,

I can iterate the command line parameter in expect script.

```
foreach arg $argv {
    puts "This is your args: $arg"
}
```

If I want to create a variable which store the size-of /length-of **$argv**
, how do I do that? The following command doesn't seem to work.

```
set argSize llength $argv
```

Comment: All the Tcl syntax rules are [documented](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- there's only 12 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops missing the square bracket as the "executable". After that, it works. Giving up too soon :-)

```
set argSize [llength $argv]
puts "argSize $argSize"
```

Comment: Square brackets mean “evaluate this bit of Tcl and use the result”.